# Reading external process Error Stream heavily impacts performance

Tags: java, python, performance, process, inputstream

I have a Java program that (including other stuff) reads from an external Python application using Input Stream.

Here is the code I use to read it:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()),
            isrError = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr), brError = new BufferedReader(isrError);
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (brError.readLine() != null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}.start();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //line is a previously declared String
    //do whatever with line
}
```

I create the thread to read the Error Stream too, because the Python application throws errors when something goes wrong (I can't edit it, it is third party software), and for some reason eventually the InputStream gets blocked if I don't read the ErrorStream.

Is there any way to make `while (brError.readLine() != null);` have less impact on performance?

Right now I am looking at performance with VisualVM, and while the Java software usually stays between 0-5% CPU usage, which is pretty nice, but around 60-65% of that usage is being used by this loop in this thread, which it's only function is to prevent the main loop from blocking. And I need to improve the performance as much as possible (This is going into industrial lines, so using resources correctly is really important).

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier handling (if you don't need the contents while running), use `redirectError(File)` in `ProcessBuilder`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("foo", "-bar");
pb.redirectError(new File("/tmp/errors.log"));
pb.start();
```

If you're getting cpu spinning from `while (brError.readLine() != null);`, you should look at what the error stream is returning. Since `readLine()` is a blocking call, it would mean that the error stream is pumping a lot of lines out.

Comment: But I don't really care about the Errors (I probably should have mentioned that before). I just "read" them so that they don't block the actual InputStream, but I don't care about Errors at all.

Comment: @Mayuso Then redirect it to `/dev/null`?

Comment: That actually makes sense, would that perform better than my current solution? I guess I should try.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the throw-away stream to characters needlessly, which may be a bit costly, especially when you're using UTF-8 (depending on the platform encoding is usually wrong, anyway).

Drop the `Reader`, use `BufferedInputStream` for the throw-away stream.

However, for external processes, the redirection is surely superior as there's no processing in Java at all.